# The entity type ClassName is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am getting the exception:

```
The entity type MyClass is not part of the model for the current context.
```

when running:

```
 IEnumerable<MyClass> queuedBuildRequests = (from p in Session.All<MyClass>()
                                                   select p).AsEnumerable<MyClass>();
```

What could be the reason for this exception? I could not figure out what I am missing here. The model edmx entries for `MyClass` look similar to other working entities. Any clue  as to what could possibly be wrong here would be very helpful. The answers for the other similar questions doesn't seem to apply to my case.

Answer (score 0):

The actual table column names and the class member variables were different cases, which was causing the problem.